# Site does not load layout

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hello everyone I have a bug that my site does not want to load its layout, I do not know where it comes from, so I left PHP, it's CSS, if you can help me please I appreciate it, I'm a beginner in it
The error that appears is in the photo below.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc5rp.png)

```
/*!
 * Style ColorTip.
 * http://jquery.com - http://fwdesign.com.br
 *
 * Copyright 2013, Jquery.com
 * Editado por: Gabriel Lopes (https://www.facebook.com/gabrielopes1);
 *
 * All rights reserved to this website.
*/
.colorTip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 63px;
    font-family:Segoe UI;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding:0px 5px;
    z-index:9999999999;       
}
.colorTipContainer {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.pointyTip,.pointyTipShadow {
    border:6px solid transparent;
    bottom:-10px;
    height:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-6px;
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
}
.pointyTipShadow {
    border-width:7px;
    bottom:-14px;
    margin-left:-7px;
}
.colorTipContainer {
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
.yellow .pointyTip {
    border-top-color:#000;
}
.yellow .pointyTipShadow {
    border-top-color:#000;
}
.yellow .colorTip {
    background-color:#000;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:0.9;
    font-family:Segoe UI;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:5px 8px;
    text-shadow:#000 0px 1px;
}
.none .pointyTip {
    border-top-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
.none .pointyTipShadow {
    border-top-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
.none .colorTip {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
/* CONEXAO */
include('site_vibe/install/config.php');
/* INSTALAR */
include('site_vibe/install/install.php');
/* MODULOS */
$caminhoModulo = 'site_vibe/modulos/';
include('site_vibe/modulos/Functions.php');
include('site_vibe/modulos/Extras.php');
if(!class_exists('Main')) {
    include('site_vibe/modulos/Main.php');
    $Main = new Main();
}
if(!class_exists('Site')) {
    include('site_vibe/modulos/Site.php');
    $Site = new Site();
}
if(!class_exists('Vibe')) {
    include('site_vibe/modulos/Vibe.php');
    $Vibe = new Vibe();
}
if(!class_exists('Usuario')) {
    include('site_vibe/modulos/Usuario.php');
    $Usuario = new Usuario();
}
$deleteUsersOn = mysql_query(sprintf("DELETE FROM online WHERE tempo < '%u'", time()));
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    $onlines_users = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM online WHERE usuario='%s'", $_SESSION['usuario']));
    $online_users_row = mysql_num_rows($onlines_users);
}else{
    $online_users_row = true;
}
$online_visit = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM online WHERE ip='%s' AND usuario='visitante'", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
$online_visit_row = mysql_num_rows($online_visit);
if(!$online_visit_row){
    $sql_users = mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO online(ip, tempo, usuario) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], strtotime('+1 minutes'), 'visitante'));
}
if(!$online_users_row){
    $sql_users = mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO online(tempo, usuario) VALUES ('%s', '%s')", strtotime('+1 minutes'), $_SESSION['usuario']));
}
if(Usuario::Logado()):
    if(Usuario::Dados('banido') == 'sim'){
        session_start();ob_start();session_unset();session_destroy();
    }
endif;
$notificacao_nao_lida = db::NumRows(db::Query("SELECT * FROM notificacao WHERE recebedor='".$_SESSION['usuario']."' AND visto='nao' AND modo='1'"));
$notificacao_seguidor_nao_lida = db::NumRows(db::Query("SELECT * FROM notificacao WHERE recebedor='".$_SESSION['usuario']."' AND visto='nao' AND tipo='seguindo' AND modo='2'"));
/* PRESENCA */
$sql_presenca = db::Query("SELECT * FROM presenca WHERE ativo='s' ORDER BY id DESC");
while($ver_presenca = db::FetchArray($sql_presenca)){
    $data_presenca = $ver_presenca['data'];
    $id_presenca = $ver_presenca['id'];
    if($data_presenca > time() - 300){
        echo('');
    }else{
        db::Query("UPDATE presenca SET ativo='n' WHERE id='$id_presenca' ");
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Vibe Habbo ~ A vibe dos seus pixels!</title>
<base href="/<?php echo $install['diretorio']; ?>">
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt-br">
<meta name="author" content="Gabriel Lopes">
<meta name="reply-to" content="biellopes1@hotmail.com">
<meta name="description" content="A vibe dos seus pixels!">
<meta name="keywords" content="vibehabbo, fã-site, rádio, música, noticias, habbo, top, forúm, topico, pixel, tirinha, valores, pixel, ducket, cambios, moedas, rico, pobre, divulgue, button, player, parceiros, mobis, mobs, mobilias, raros, gabriel lopes, fwdesign, administradores, locutor, jornalista, moderador, fã-center, pagina inicial, rede socias, facebook, twitter, fw, fwdesign">
<meta name="url" content="http://vibehabbo.com.br"/>
<meta name="Robots" content="index,follow">
<meta name="language" content="pt_BR">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="VibeHabbo.Com.Br - Feed RRS" href="http://vibehabbo.com.br/feed" />
<!-- Styles -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/fwcss.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/shadowbox.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/colortips.css"/>
<!-- Jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-nav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/colortip.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/shadowbox.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/principal.js"</script>
<!-- HTML 5 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<style>
#modal { background:#19140D; position:fixed; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0 ;z-index:99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;}
#modal #alerta { width:387px; position:fixed; cursor:move; }
</style>
<script>
var Site = '/<?php echo $install['diretorio']; ?>';
</script>
<body>
<div id="content_topo">
<div id="content_player_canto">
<div id="avatar-player" style="width:60px; height:65px; float:left; margin:6px 0 0 1px; background:url(imagens/avatar.png) 1px -13px; cursor:pointer;" onClick="player.atualizar('avatar');">
<div id="botao_mais_locutor_player_canto"></div>
</div>
<div id="content_botao_base_play_pause">

    <div id="content_botao_play_pause"><div id="icone_pause_player"></div></div>

</div>
<div id="content_ouvintes">
<div id="total_ouvintes" class="text_total_ouvintes_player ver-ouvintes-player" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="player.atualizar('ouvintes');">...</div>
<div id="title_ouv_player" class="text_title_ouvintes_player">ouv.</div>
</div>
<div id="content_nome_programa_locutor_player">
<div id="content_insert_nome_programa_locutor_player" class="text_nome_programa_locutor_player ver-locutor-player" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="player.atualizar('locutor');">carregando</div>
</div>
<div id="content_nome_programa_locutor_player">
<div id="content_insert_nome_programa_locutor_player" class="text_nome_programa_locutor_player ver-programa-player" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="player.atualizar('programa');"><marquee height="19" scrollamount="4" scrolldelay="4" direction="left">carregando</marquee></div>
</div>
<div id="botao_pedido_player">
<div id="botao_pedido_player_cima"></div>
<a href="radio/pedidos"><div id="insert_botao_text_pedido_player" class="text_botao_pedido_player">Fazer pedido</div></a>
</div>
</div>
<?php if(!Usuario::Logado()): ?>
<form action="javascript:;" id="form-login">
<div id="content_conta_canto_esq" style="z-index:999999999;">
<div id="content_notificacao_login">
<div id="flecha_content_notificacao"></div>
<div id="insert_notificacao_mostra_login">
<div id="titulo_content_notificacao">
<div id="content_title_notificacao_login" class="text_titulo_insert_notificacao">login</div>
<a href="usuario/register"><div id="botao_configuracoes_notificacao" class="text_botao_configuracao">Crie sua conta</div></a>
</div>
<div id="content_insert_notificacao_login">
<div id="insert_titulo_box_login" class="text_titulo_box_lados">E-mail ou nick:</div>
<input type="text" id="username-login" style="width:246px;"/>
<div id="insert_titulo_box_login" class="text_titulo_box_lados">
<div id="botao_esqueceu_senha" class="text_botao_esqueceu_senha">Esqueceu a senha?</div>
Senha:</div>
<input id="password-login"type="password" style="width:246px;"/>
</div>
</div>
<div id="botao_content_notificacao">
<div id="content_title_botao_vermais_notificacao" class="text_botao_vermais_notificacao logar-submit">fazer login</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="insert_conta_canto_esq">
<div id="icone_conta_canto_esq"></div>
</div>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<!-- inicia logado -->
<div id="content_logado_canto">
<div style="width:60px; height:46px; float:left; margin:3px 0 0 0; background:url(https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&user=<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?>&action=std&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml&size=b) 1px -13px;">
<div id="botao_editar_dados_logado_canto">
<div id="icone_editar_dados_logado_canto"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content_logado_canto_opcoes">
<!-- inicia notificacao -->
<div id="content_notificacao">
<div id="flecha_content_notificacao"></div>
<div id="insert_notificacao_mostra">
<div id="titulo_content_notificacao">
<div id="icone_insert_notificacao"></div>
<div id="content_title_notificacao" class="text_titulo_insert_notificacao">notificações</div>
<div id="botao_configuracoes_notificacao" class="text_botao_configuracao">Configurações</div>
</div>
<div style="height:383px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; clear:both;" id="recebe-notificacao-total">
<?php include('Notificacao.php'); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div id="botao_content_notificacao"><div id="content_title_botao_vermais_notificacao" class="text_botao_vermais_notificacao">ver todas notificações</div></div>
</div>
<!-- encerra notificacao -->
<!-- inicia notificacao seguidores -->
<div id="content_notificacao_solicitacao">
<div id="flecha_content_notificacao"></div>
<div id="insert_notificacao_mostra">
<div id="titulo_content_notificacao">
<div id="content_title_notificacao_solicitacao" class="text_titulo_insert_notificacao">seguidores</div>
<div id="botao_configuracoes_notificacao" class="text_botao_configuracao">Configurações</div>
</div>
<div style="height:383px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; clear:both;" id="recebe-seguidores-total">
<?php include('Seguidor.php'); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div id="botao_content_notificacao"><div id="content_title_botao_vermais_notificacao" class="text_botao_vermais_notificacao">ver todos seguidores</div></div>
</div>
<!-- encerra notificacao -->
<!-- inicia notificacao marcar presensa -->
<div id="content_notificacao_presenca">
<div id="flecha_content_notificacao"></div>
<div id="insert_notificacao_mostra_presenca">
<div id="titulo_content_notificacao">
<div id="content_title_notificacao_marcar_presenca" class="text_titulo_insert_notificacao">código de presença</div>
<div id="botao_codigos_hoje_notificacao" class="text_botao_codigos_hoje">Códigos de Hoje</div>
</div>
<div style="height:189px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; clear:both;">
<div id="content_insert_presenca_notificacao">
<div id="insert_title_presenca_notificacao" class="text_insert_title_presenca_notificacao">Digite o Código de presença abaixo</div>
<div id="content_input_botao_codigo_presenca">
<style>
#input_insert_codigo_presenca {width:113px; height:28px; float:left; padding:0px; margin:6px 0 0 16px; background:#D9D9D9; border:none; font-family:Segoe UI; font-size:15px; color:#333; font-weight:bold;}
#input_insert_codigo_presenca:focus, #input_insert_codigo_presenca:hover {border:0px; box-shadow:0px 0px 0px; margin:6px 0 0 16px;}
</style>
<form id="gerar-presenca" action="javascript:;">
<div id="base_input_codigo_presenca"><input id="input_insert_codigo_presenca" type="text"/></div>
<div id="botao_codigo_presenca_gerar">
<div id="insert_botao_codigo_presenca_gerar_title" class="text_insert_botao_presenca_gerar">Gerar código</div>
</div>
</form>
<!--
<div id="total_pontos_gerados_presenca_notificacao" class="text_total_pontos_horas_gerados_presenca">Você gerou 1 PONTO</div>
<div id="total_horas_gerados_presenca_notificacao" class="text_total_pontos_horas_gerados_presenca">há 22 horas</div>
<div id="total_pontos_gerados_presenca_notificacao" class="text_total_pontos_horas_gerados_presenca">Você gerou 1 PONTO</div>
<div id="total_horas_gerados_presenca_notificacao" class="text_total_pontos_horas_gerados_presenca">há 22 horas</div>
<div id="total_pontos_gerados_presenca_notificacao" class="text_total_pontos_horas_gerados_presenca">Você gerou 1 PONTO</div>
<div id="total_horas_gerados_presenca_notificacao" class="text_total_pontos_horas_gerados_presenca">há 22 horas</div>
<div id="total_pontos_gerados_presenca_notificacao" class="text_total_pontos_horas_gerados_presenca">Você gerou 1 PONTO</div>
<div id="total_horas_gerados_presenca_notificacao" class="text_total_pontos_horas_gerados_presenca">há 22 horas</div>
-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="botao_content_notificacao"><div id="content_title_botao_vermais_notificacao" class="text_botao_vermais_notificacao">ver todos códigos gerados</div></div>
</div>
<!-- encerra notificacao marcar presenca -->
<div id="icone_notificacao_logado"><div id="content_total_notificacoes" class="text_total_notificacoes total-notificao-tudo"><?php echo $notificacao_nao_lida; ?></div></div>
<div id="icone_solicitacao_logado"><div id="content_total_notificacoes" class="text_total_notificacoes total-notificao-seguidor"><?php echo $notificacao_seguidor_nao_lida; ?></div></div>
<a href="usuario/gerar-moedas"><div id="icone_creditos_logado"></div></a>
<div id="icone_marcar_presenca_logado"></div>
<a href="usuario/configuracao"><div id="icone_configuracao_logado"></div></a>
<a href="usuario/postar-tirinha"><div id="icone_home_logado"></div></a>
<a href="usuario/postar-pixel"><div id="icone_galeria_logado"></div></a>
<a href="usuario/postar-topico"><div id="icone_topico_logado"></div></a>
</div>
<div id="botao_sair_logado_canto" onClick="usuario.deslogar();">
<div id="insert_botao_sair_logado_canto" class="text_sair_logado_canto">sair</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- encerra logado -->
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- inicia pesquisar -->
<div id="content_pesquisar_canto_esq">
<!-- caixa lado pesquisa -->
<div id="content_pesquisa_canto_esq_lado">
<div id="icone_flecha_content_pesquisa_canto_esq"></div>
<div id="content_insert_pesquisa_principal_canto_esq">
<style>
#input_pesquisar_canto_lado_esq {width:140px; height:20px; padding:0px; float:left; margin:11px 0 0 19px; background:#558EC0; border:none; font-family:Segoe UI; font-size:13px; color:#FFF; line-height:1.0em;}
#input_pesquisar_canto_lado_esq:focus, #input_pesquisar_canto_lado_esq:hover {border:0px; box-shadow:0px 0px 0px; margin:11px 0 0 19px;}</style>
<form action="javascript:;" id="pesquisar-canto">
<input id="input_pesquisar_canto_lado_esq" type="text" value="Pesquisar usuário"/>
</form>
<div id="icone_pesquisa_canto_esq_small"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- caixa lado pesquisa -->
<div id="insert_content_pesquisar_canto_esq">
<div id="icone_pesquisar_canto_esq"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- encerra pesquisar -->
<div id="insert_content_topo">
<style>
#content_paginacao_slide a {width:13px; height:13px; float:left; margin:0 7px 0 0; background:rgba(500,500,500,0.7); border-radius:100%; cursor:pointer; transition:0.3s;}
#content_paginacao_slide a.activeSlide {width:13px; height:13px; float:left; margin:0 7px 0 0; background:#FF0033; border-radius:100%; cursor:pointer;}
</style>
<div id="content_paginacao_slide" style="position:absolute; z-index:100;">
</div>
<div id="recebe-slide" style="width:552px; height:310px; float:left;">
<div id="imagem_principal_slide" style="background:url(http://imgur.com/Pyp3XCI.png);">
<div id="contagem_segundos_slide" class="text_contagem_segundos_slide" style="opacity:0.0;">Próximo slide: <b>10S</b></div>
<div id="content_info_slide">
<div id="barra_carregando_slide_normal">
<div id="barra_carregando_slide_carregado" style="width:190px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="insert_content_info_slide">
<div id="insert_text_info_slide">
<div id="insert_text_info_slide_grande" class="text_insert_info_slide_grande">Bem-vindo a versão 3!</div>
<div id="insert_text_info_slide_pequeno" class="text_insert_info_slide_pequeno">Cadastre-se em nosso site !</div>
</div>
<div id="botao_mais_info_slide">
<div id="botao_mais_info_slide_cima"></div>
<div id="insert_botao_text_info_slide" class="text_botao_mais_info_slide">Ir para o site</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- fim slide -->
<div id="imagem_principal_slide" style="background:url(http://i.imgur.com/8pkjwwb.png);">
<div id="contagem_segundos_slide" class="text_contagem_segundos_slide" style="opacity:0.0;">Próximo slide: <b>10S</b></div>
<div id="content_info_slide">
<div id="barra_carregando_slide_normal">
<div id="barra_carregando_slide_carregado" style="width:190px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="insert_content_info_slide">
<div id="insert_text_info_slide">
<div id="insert_text_info_slide_grande" class="text_insert_info_slide_grande">Facebook da VibeHabbo!</div>
<div id="insert_text_info_slide_pequeno" class="text_insert_info_slide_pequeno">fica ligando em nosso facebook</div>
</div>
<div id="botao_mais_info_slide">
<div id="botao_mais_info_slide_cima"></div>
<div id="insert_botao_text_info_slide" class="text_botao_mais_info_slide">Ir para o site</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- fim slide -->
</div>
<div id="logo_site_principal"></div>
<div id="content_palcos_mobilias_recentes">
<div id="palco_mobilias_recentes_1"><div id="base_mobilia_palco_1" style="background:url(imagens/mobis_recentes/1.png) no-repeat center;"></div></div>
<div id="palco_mobilias_recentes_2"><div id="base_mobilia_palco_1" style="background:url(imagens/mobis_recentes/9.png) no-repeat center;"></div></div>
<div id="palco_mobilias_recentes_3"><div id="base_mobilia_palco_1" style="background:url(imagens/mobis_recentes/8.png) no-repeat center;"></div></div>
<div id="palco_mobilias_recentes_4"><div id="base_mobilia_palco_1" style="background:url(imagens/mobis_recentes/2.png) no-repeat center;"></div></div>
<div id="palco_mobilias_recentes_5"><div id="base_mobilia_palco_1" style="background:url(imagens/mobis_recentes/3.png) no-repeat center;"></div></div>
<div id="palco_mobilias_recentes_6"><div id="base_mobilia_palco_1" style="background:url(imagens/mobis_recentes/6.png) no-repeat center;"></div></div>
<div id="palco_mobilias_recentes_9"><div id="base_mobilia_palco_1" style="background:url(imagens/mobis_recentes/7.png) no-repeat center;"></div></div>
<div id="palco_mobilias_recentes_7"><div id="base_mobilia_palco_1" style="background:url(imagens/mobis_recentes/5.png) no-repeat center;"></div></div>
<div id="palco_mobilias_recentes_8"><div id="base_mobilia_palco_1" style="background:url(imagens/mobis_recentes/4.png) no-repeat center;"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content_base_corpo_site">
<div id="info_barra_corpo_site">
<div id="content_insert_info_barra_corpo_site">
<div id="icone_insert_info_barra_corpo_site"></div>
<div id="insert_text_info_barra_corpo_site" class="text_insert_info_barra_corpo_site">Olá <b>usuários</b>, gostariamos de saber oque acharam do nosso novo site?</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="corpo_site">
<?php
    Site::Paginas('Paginas');
?>  
</div>
<div id="content_rodape">
<div id="content_text_creditos_rodape" class="text_creditos_rodape">Copyrights © 2013 - 2014 | Vibe Habbo. Todos os direitos reservados a este site da web. Este site não é de propriedade ou operado pela Sulake Corporation e não é parte do Habbo Hotel®.</div>
<div id="logo_vibe_rodape"></div>
<div id="base_logo_fw_rodape"><a href="http://fwdesign.com.br" target="_blank"><div id="logo_fw_rodape"></div></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try looking in the navigator console to see if there are any errors and keep going from there

Comment: Typo (missing `>`) here: `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"</script>`

Comment: I searched but I did not understand anything and I did not find

Comment: And use a parameterized queries, sprintf() is not sufficient or safe.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what your script header tags should look like. Notice how there is a `>` symbol after each src element. This denotes the closing of the tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-nav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/colortip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/principal.js"></script>
```

It's also recommended to use `_` instead of spaces in your folder name to help reduce errors. So `http://habbomania.esy.es/vibe v3/index.php` should be `http://habbomania.esy.es/vibe_v3/index.php`.

Comment: The same mistake continues

Comment: Can you post your updated code? It looks like you locked down the site link, I'm no longer able to see the page.

Comment: http://habbomania.esy.es/vibe_v3/index.php

Comment: Look in the F12 Error Console & Network tab, there are many errors, E.g. http://habbomania.esy.es/scripts/jquery.js is a 404 not found ... The same is true for all the js/css

Comment: What is the folder & file permission set to? I'm seeing a 403 error when accessing `css/fwcss.css`. As Alex K. mentioned, there are many resource errors in the console.

Comment: I changed a few things but the same mistake continues